# Query on a Foreign Key number

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to run a query that will bring back products which are approved and have a producttype(fk) id of 5. at the moment it just returns all approved products and ignores the producttype.

my current code.

```
$products =Product::where('approved', '=', 1, 'AND','producttype_id', '=', 5)->orderBy('productname');
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split and chain `where()` (or pass array of conditions) method like this:

```
<?php
// chaining
$products = Product::where('approved', 1)->where('producttype_id', 5)->orderBy('productname')->get();

// passing array of conditions
$products = Product::where([
    [ 'approved', '=', 1 ],
    [ 'producttype_id', '=', 5 ]
])->orderBy('productname')->get();
```

More information: [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: Nice one, what if i wanted to get multiple producttype_id's would i use 'or'?

Comment: Use `whereIn()`: `$products = Product::where('approved', 1)->whereIn('producttype_id', [ 5, 6, 7 ])->get();`

Answer (score 0):

You can always pass a list, ie:

```
$products =Product::where([
    ['approved', '=', 1],
    ['producttype_id', '=', 5],
])->orderBy('productname');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries